# An inverse problem for Grothendieck rings of varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, motives, grothendieck-rings, projective-varieties

Suppose $A$ is a given commutative ring, and suppose that one knows that $A$ is isomorphic to the Grothendieck ring of $k$-varieties for some unknown field $k$.

Can $k$ be recovered from $A$ ? If not, what about the characteristic of $k$ ?

A related question is obviously the following: if $k$ and $k'$ are nonisomorphic fields, can the Grothendiek rings $K_0(V_k)$ and $K_0(V_{k'})$ be isomorphic ?

Comment: I think the field is countable (or finite) if and only if the Grothendieck ring is countable.

Comment: A related question is whether every automorphism of $K_0(V_{\mathbb C})$ comes from that of $\mathbb C
$.

Comment: And another one: if $L/K$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$, what does $K_0(Var/L)^G$ have to do with $K_0(Var/K)$?

Comment: I suspect that these Grothedieck rings are isomorphic for an arithmetically profinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and for its fields of norms.

Comment: @MikhailBondarko : could you describe your ideas in an answer ?

Comment: Sorry; this statement is certainly fulfilled for the corresponding "$0$-dimensional smooth Grothendiecks rings"; yet already for a (finite) inseparable extension of the field of norms it is not clear how to find a "preimage" of its class over the starting arithmetically profinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. So, my conjecture is probably wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't written a complete proof, but I expect your last (and therefore) first question to have a negative answer. Here is what I believe is a counterexample. Let $k$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ (a countable number of variables). We can view this as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. We have a homomorphism $e:K_0(V_k)\to K_0(V_\mathbb{C})$ given by sending the symbol of a variety $[X]$ to $[X\otimes \mathbb{C}]$. This is seen to be surjective because any complex variety can be defined over a finitely generated field, and therefore over $k$. I expect this to be injective as well. It would be enough to show that for (reducible) $k$-varieties  $X$ and $Y$, $[X]-[Y]=0$ when it lies in the kernel of $e$. If $e([X]-[Y])=0$, we have finite   partitions into locally closed sets $X\otimes \mathbb{C}= \cup X_i$ and $Y\otimes \mathbb{C}= \cup Y_i$ such that $X_i\cong Y_i$. As before, the partitions and isomorphisms should be definable over $k$, so $[X]-[Y]=0$.

Comment: I don't think this will work, because each complex variety is defined over a different finitely generated field, and they won't all be contained in the image of $k$.

Comment: You're probably right that there may be inconsistencies in the definig fields. But I've leave my answer up in case there is a way to fix it.